# Error Executing Ruby File via exec()

Tags: php, ruby

I need to execute a Ruby file via PHP on Debian 8 & Apache server.

The current code looks like

```php
exec('/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby /var/www/project/_backend/pull-data.rb clients', $null, $returnVal);
echo intval($returnVal);
```

In this example, `$returnVal` (see [exec()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php)) returns 1 which could be missing permissions for executing the specific file.

The current permissions for `pull-data.rb`:
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data pull-data.rb`

Watching the Apache error log a **Load Error** occures when the php scripts calls the ruby exec command:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- mysql2 (LoadError)
```

The MySQL2 gem is installed and executing the Ruby file via the shell `ruby` command just works fine.

Thanks,
Roman

Comment: What happens when you remove the full path and let RVM pick the ruby version to run? (`/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby` to just `ruby`)

Comment: Probably because you are using RVM and installed `mysql2`, and any other gem into a gemset. Just calling that specific version of ruby will not invoke the installed gemset. You are going to need to tell it which version of ruby, as well as the gemset to use.

Comment: I already unsuccessfully tried executing the command without the Ruby path: `sh: 1: ruby: not found`. The only Ruby version installed by RVM is 2.1.1.

Comment: What @JustinWood said is correct, you will need to either add RVM to your execution path (via a bashrc or bash_profile file): `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. After adding the line to `.bashrc` the ruby command is not being found anymore